# process.on('signal') isn't working in node.js v18

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to catch "CTRL-C" on a command line node.js script.

```
process.on('signal', async (signal) => {
    console.log('signal: ', signal);
    if (signal === 'SIGINT') {
        console.log('Received SIGINT. Calling save function...');
        await amazon.saveData();
    }

    process.exit(0);
});
```

It doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding directly to the SIGINT event should work:

```js
process.on('SIGINT', async (signal) => {
    console.log('signal: ', signal);

    console.log('Received SIGINT. Calling save function...');
    await amazon.saveData();

    process.exit(0);
});
```

You can find a list of supported events in the API reference: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#signal-events

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work

```
process.on('SIGINT', async (signal) => {
    // ..
    console.log('Received SIGINT. Calling save function...');

});
```